# undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class error with subclasses on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm just in the beginning phase of building my app - so nothing too serious here. It works fine in my local environment, but seems to be crashing on heroku.

The code is like so:

I have a User model in devise.
I have 2 sub classes under User, Authors and Readers.

The form for adding a reader looks like so:

```
<%= form_for(@reader, :url => user_registration_path) do |f| %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :zipcode %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :zipcode %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

The controller has:

```
  def index
    @reader = Reader.new
  end
```

And the model is simply:

```
Class Reader < User
end
```

While I haven't tried to create a new user yet using the form, I'm not getting any error loading the page in my local environment. Yet on heroku, I'm getting `undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class`.

I've raked the DB, and restarted the server with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't you feel that is wrong using `user_registration_path` as action for the `reader` model form?

Comment: To discard the obvious first: is that form in index.html.erb? It looks like @reader is not set.

Comment: @fotanus, originally yes - but its going to live in the user table, and it isn't giving me any errors locally. So I don't see why that'd be the problem on heroku.

Comment: good call - it was in a partial and I didnt realize I was on the wrong view, feel free to post that as an answer - I'll mark correct @Ghar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like @reader is not set.
The form is not in index.html.erb.
it must be the partial _form.html.erb used by the new and edit actions. So you have to set @reader in those actions in the readers controller